# How do I center images in UITableViewCells programmatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I would like my iOS app to display images in every prototype [`UITableViewCell`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/) in the [`UITableView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/). My `UITableView` has been created in a Storyboard and the image is specified programmatically with the [`imageView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/imageView) property, not with [`NSLayoutConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/) and Auto Layout.

I found that the alignment of the [`UIImages`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/) varies from the widths of the icons. For instance, in the following image there are two blue icons which have a different width. The second icon with the `UILabel` next to it seems to be not properly aligned if compared to the other row at the top:

[image]

I guess this misplacement can be fixed by using Auto Layout by placing an image in the prototype cell, and then setting up constraints for every icon. I think this is tedious work and there should be a better way because the `imageView` property really comes in handy in this case. It doses almost the job for you. Probably a property to center the image so even if images in cells don't have equal widths it all looks fine.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with using autolayout; this is one of the use cases for it. If this is a static tableview there is a little bit of work for each cell but not much.

Comment: Thanks @RoboticCat. I'm going to use AutoLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get to understand Constraints, they're not that bad, and cells are one of the simplest cases to configure.

In this case, just set a constraint on the width (i.e., set the width to be XX), another constraint to centre it vertically within the cell, and then a couple constraints on the label next to the image (left and right).

One of the reasons that constraints are becoming so important is because of the varying widths of screens (and hence, cells in tableviews) so to get them looking right, constraints do make it much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content mode on the UIImageView. Try the centre option.

```
imageView.contentMode = .center
```

Comment: Thanks. This approach doesn't work. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I created an `UIImageView`, set its `contentMode` and then assigned it to a table view cell with `imageView.view`. The code compiles but nothing changes.

Comment: Create your own custom cell. If the issue remains, look at the source pngs. In your example the second cells text is also offset to the left. A custom cell will fix this.